# filter non matching key-points with list comprehension

Tags: python, opencv

I have a list of key-points matches generated using

```
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L1,crossCheck=True)
    matches = bf.match(des1,des2)
```

I want to filter the the non-relevant key-points from my `kps1,kps2` lists based on the matches. I tried using the `DMatch.trainIdx`, `DMatch.queryIdx` fields in this way:

```
new_kps1 = [kp if idx in match.trainIdx for idx,kp in enumerate(kps1) for match in matches]
```

---

I eventually did it this way:

```
ls1 = []
ls2 = []
for m in matches:
    ls1 += [kps1[m.trainIdx]]
    ls2 += [kps2[m.queryIdx]]
```

Is this possible somehow in a list comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Python idiom `zip(*x)` to transpose a list of tuples to a tuple of lists. This way you can initially just record tuples:

```
x = [(kps1[m.trainIdx], kps2[m.queryIdx]) for m in matches]
ls1, ls2 = map(list, zip(*x))
```

You could even put this in one line, at the cost of readability:

```
ls1, ls2 = map(list, zip(*[(kps1[m.trainIdx], kps2[m.queryIdx]) for m in matches]))
```